# Can we make nested database in MySQL? If yes how?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I don't know if it has another term for it but I want to basically create a directorial database having different databases in one major database and each containing their respective tables. Is there any way to do that in MySQL?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Please help me I might be wrong in my interpretations since  I'm very new to dealing with databases and websites

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but no, databases inside databases are not possible.

Comment: could you please just check out that picture and tell me what is that structure called? or how to make it?I mean i just need little guidance to make it

Comment: Maybe you should rather describe, what you want to do and why.

Comment: I have seen this kind of structure and i want to implement the same.I have some DB structures.The main one is exam_db and in that i have to put  the other dbs, faculty_db+its tables then ,batch_2015 +its tables etc  so on.....just like here in the picture(identical->accessess 6 identical..and so on all in major directory/DB called Access6).so i want to do like this

Does that explain?

Comment: I know how to create single database though but putting Dbs in such a structure I don't know how to do it

Comment: No, you already said all this. Why do you want to do this? What ultimate goal do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, it is not possible to make a nested database in MySQL.**

MySQL supports a simple and flat structure. You cannot nest databases (and of course not tables, nor fields).

If you want to group databases together in MySQL for any reason (like availability), then you can use a common prefix when naming them. For example, if you want to develop an HRM (Human Resource Management System), and it has let's say 3 parts namely: Inventory, Attendance and Leaves, then you can have the following database:

- HRM_INVENTORY  (created by `CREATE DATABASE HRM_INVENTORY;`)
- HRM_ATTENDANCE (created by `CREATE DATABASE HRM_ATTENDANCE;`)
- HRM_LEAVES     (created by `CREATE DATABASE HRM_LEAVES;`)

Now regarding the image that you have shared in your question, PHPMyAdmin only tries to find common prefixes and group them together to make them easy to find for the user. For example if you create the 3 databases I just mentioned, PHPMyAdmin will group them together under **HRM** and if you collapse it, you can see all the three.

Comment: Thank you so much . You saved my life :p That's all i wanted to know

Comment: @nikitamullick Please click the check to the left of this answer so others know the problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: Done.thanks for that too...I am new to stackoverflow too :p